# can not save microsoft office2011 files for mac by using osxfuse for developing

Tags: macos, osxfuse

I am using osxfuse to develop a network disk with our service on mac osx, when I open a office2011 file and save in my disk, it will appear this error as below:

> "you cannot save while the file is in use by another process.try saving the file with a new name."

[image]

but it is fine for office 2016. I am confusing about this and do not know how to resolve it?
who can help you?

Answer (score 0):

I am working on my own FUSE file system and also had this problem. I found that in my case it was because I mounted the file system with the "noapplexattr" option.

It looks like MS Word requires applexattr.

Answer (score 0):

MS Office apps uses extended attributes a lot. So your fs should has support of xattrs at least via apple double files (._fileName)

Also i found that MS Word likes to use exchange operation while saving files.

But it also may be an issues in your read/write/move methods implementation.

When i have such doubts - i use loopbackFS example app and just compare how it works with my FS.